# Why would onTouch() generate FATAL EXCEPTION when returning false?

Tags: android, motion, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I wrote a simple MotionEvent exercise in which all I do is log the parameters of the event. I do that by implementing **OnTouchListener** and overriding **onTouch()** in the main activity.

For one button, I return **true** at the end of onTouch(). No problems there.

For another button, I return **false** at the end of onTouch(). This is where it gets interesting. By mere returning 'false', a FATAL EXCEPTION is thrown with a tiny hint which I don't really understand: "recycled twice!".

What does this mean?

Update: per the suggestion in the comment below, I am adding the details of the exception from LogCat:

```
03-08 10:35:14.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 10:35:14.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(521): java.lang.RuntimeException: MotionEvent{405215b0 action=0 x=66.0 y=78.0 pressure=1.0 size=0.0} recycled twice!
03-08 10:35:14.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(521):     at android.view.MotionEvent.recycle(MotionEvent.java:659)
03-08 10:35:14.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(521):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1880)
03-08 10:35:14.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(521):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 10:35:14.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(521):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-08 10:35:14.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
03-08 10:35:14.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 10:35:14.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-08 10:35:14.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-08 10:35:14.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-08 10:35:14.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(521):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You need to show us your LogCat o/p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you recycling and then passing `false`?

The framework will assume that the MotionEvent is still valid if you return false and will do its own processing with it.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#recycle%28%29):

> Recycle the MotionEvent, to be re-used
>   by a later caller. After calling this
>   function you must not ever touch the
>   event again.

Comment: I think that the answer to your question is Yes: In addition to onTouch in the main activity, I override onTouchEvent() in subclassed buttons. Only when onTouch() returns false, onTouchEvent() gets called, and that onTouchEvent() ends with **event.recycle(); return false;** Am I not allowed to return false after event.recycle()? Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: Try the docs link I posted for more info. Yes, you should not call event.recycle() if you're going to return false, because the framework will send the same MotionEvent to another listener after yours.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear. The docs link contains only one line about recycle()... The guys at Google must be assuming that all Android developers are all geniuses. :)

Comment: hehe, yep. Although the error message you got was what tipped me off.